# MySQL "Left Outer Join" Issue

Tags: mysql, outer-join

Big Issue in "Left Outer Join"

"mydata" table schema 
pk1 as varchar , pk2 as varchar,pk3 as datatime, value1 as int,value2 as int

Left Outer Join SQL

```
select a.pk1,a.pk3,a.value1,a.value2,b.value1,b.value2 
from mydata as a 
left outer join mydata as b 
    on (a.pk1=b.pk1 and b.pk2='data2' and a.pk3=b.pk3) 
where a.pk1='abc' and a.pk2='data1' and a.pk3>='2016/5/3 15:00' and
    a.pk3 <= '2016/5/3 16:00'
```

it's OK when pk3 use >= & <= , select result

```
abc ,2016/5/3 15:00 , 1,1,2,2 
abc ,2016/5/3 15:30 , 2,2,9,9 
abc ,2016/5/3 16:00 , 3,3,12,12
```

but when i use a.pk3='2016/5/3 15:00', select result

```
abc ,2016/5/3 15:00 , 1,1,null,null
```

i try it at MS SQL, select result

```
abc ,2016/5/3 15:00 , 1,1,2,2
```

what's the different ??? and how should i fix MySQL sql stirng as i need the result which MS SQL does??

======================

```
CREATE TABLE `mydata` (
`pk1` char(20) NOT NULL,
`pk2` char(10) NOT NULL,
`pk3` datetime NOT NULL,
`value1` int NOT NULL,
`value2` int NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`pk1`,`pk2`,`pk3`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

by the way ,if i use a.pk3>='2016/5/3 15:00' and a.pk3 <= '2016/5/3 15:00' , and the select result

```
abc ,2016/5/3 15:00 , 1,1,2,2
```

========================

```
select a.pk1,a.pk3,a.value1,a.value2,b.value1,b.value2 
from mydata as a 
left outer join mydata as b 
    on (a.pk1=b.pk1 and b.pk2='data2' and a.pk3=b.pk3) 
where a.pk1='abc' and a.pk2='data1' and a.pk3>='2016/5/3 15:00' 

abc ,2016/5/3 15:00 , 1,1,2,2 
abc ,2016/5/3 15:30 , 2,2,9,9 
abc ,2016/5/3 16:00 , 3,3,12,12 
....
....
```

=========================

yes, fix sql string to a.pk3=convert('2016/5/1 09:30', datetime) will solve this problem.

Comment: Your result is confusing me.  If the `WHERE` clause passed for that record, you should ideally be getting the same values from `mydata` as with the first clause.  Can you include a SQL Fiddle with actual data so we may take a closer look?

Comment: Please provide at least the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query looks simple enough. I guess `mydata` table doesn't have a record for `pk3='2016/5/3 15:00'` **in MySQL**.

You can test this using the query
`select * from mydata where pk3='2016/5/3 15:00'`
in **MySQL**

If the above query returns nothing but you can see a record for `pk3='2016/5/3 15:00'`, it's probably a case of formatting, in which case you need to convert to datetime

`select * from mydata where pk3=convert('2016/5/3 15:00', datetime)`

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't provide more code and the inserted data, we can only guess:

The timestamps in your table might be some seconds or milliseconds later. It would match the clause `a.pk3 >= '2016/5/3 15:00' AND a.pk3 <= '2016/5/3 16:00'` but isn't equal to the first value. In your display format the seconds and milliseconds are just cut off, but comparison depends on content, not what's displayed.